# Submit a form automatically after a certain amount of time has elapsed

Tags: javascript, forms, timer

I have a timer and I want to submit a form after a certain amount of time has elapsed.

```
if (elapsedSeconds === 1800) {
document.getElementById("formid").submit();
}
```

[image: Screenshot of code]

I have tested it by replacing 1800 with 10 and it doesn't submit the form after 10 seconds.

Comment: Can you share more of the surrounding code please?

Comment: Here it is: http://puu.sh/gZEPm/2ad02ef11e.png

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use setTimeout() instead of setInterval(). Try using `setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("formid").submit();},1800000)`

Comment: Thank you that works. Although 1800 is in ms so I will convert it to seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The `if(elapsedSeconds==1800){...}` needs to be within the `updateTimer` method. Otherwise you're only executing once after page load and never again.

otherwise, look into using a `setTimeout` and save yourself the hassle of counters:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  document.getElementById('formid').submit();
}, 30 * 60e3 /* 30 minutes */);
```

if you need to cancel it, store the reference:

```
var to = setTimeout(...);

/* later on */
clearTimeout(to); // stops the timeout from executing (assuming it hasn't already)
```